# Multi-thread conversation in django (like Reddit)

Tags: django, model

I have an app which essentially a conversation system (much like reddit).

Where a post can have multiple replies, and a reply and have multiplies, and a reply to a reply can have multiple replies (etc.)

I've made the model like this:

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    replies = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

and the view:

```
discussions = Discussions.objects.all()
```

and the template looks like this:

```
{% for discussion in discussions %}
    {{ discussion.message }}
{% endfor %}
```

How would I go about making a system where I can output all replies like this?

```
discussion
    reply
        reply
    reply
        reply
            reply
                reply
```

Which would go down as far as it needs to to ensure all replies are listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless a reply can be a reply to multiple posts, a `ManyToManyField` isn't what you want.  You just need a `ForeignKey`:

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', 
        null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can get to a Discussion's replies with `Discussion.replies`.

Unfortunately, there's no way to do a recursion in Django's template language, so you have to either 1) run a recursive function to get a "flattened" list of replies, and put that in the context, or 2) write a function that can be called recursively that uses a template to generate each level, which would look something like:

```
_DiscussionTemplate = Template("""
<li>{{ discussion.message }}{% if replies %}
    <ul>
        {% for reply in replies %}
        {{ reply }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}</li>
""".strip())

class Discussion(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', 
        null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def html(self):
        return _DiscussionTemplate.render(Context({
            'discussion': self,
            'replies': [reply.html() for reply in self.replies.all()]
        }))
```

Then in your top-level template, you just need:

```
<ul>
    {% for d in discussions %}
    {{ d.html }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Apply CSS as desired to make it look nice.

**EDIT:** Root discussions are those in `Discussion.objects.filter(reply_to=None)`.  And all the code, `_DiscussionTemplate` included, goes in your `models.py`.  This way, `_DiscussionTemplate` is initialized once when the module loads.

**EDIT 2:** Putting the HTML in a template file is pretty straightforward.  Change the view code that sets `_DiscussionTemplate` to:

```
_DiscussionTemplate = loader.get_template("discussiontemplate.html")
```

Then create `discussiontemplate.html`:

```
<li>{{ discussion.message }}{% if replies %}
    <ul>
        {% for reply in replies %}
        {{ reply }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}</li>
```

Set the path to the template file as needed.

Comment: Where does _DiscussionTemplate go? Is it in my model? Do i have to import template?

Comment: symmetrical=False throw up an error so i removed it, will this still work?

Comment: How can I tell which are root discussions?

Comment: Just a follow up, this works well. However, is there any way to move the template from the model into it's own template? So it can reside in templates/includes/discussiontemplate ?

Comment: I have another field (votes, which is an integer field, obviously mimicking reddit's noting system) i want to order by votes (desc). How would i do that?

Comment: Replace `self.replies.all()` with `self.replies.all().order_by('-votes')`.

Comment: Theres a follow up discussion over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950155/reddit-style-voting-with-django

If you fancy lending another helping hand :)

Comment: A follow up to this

What does the reply.html() in reply.html() for reply in self.replies.all() do? Im aware the second part is a for loop retrieving all the replies

Comment: It specifies what values you want in the list.  List comprehensions can be generalized as `[f(k) for k in X] = [f(X[0]), f(X[1]), ... f(X[N-1])]` where `f(k)` is some function of `k`, `X` is your iterable (list, tuple, dict, file, whatever), and `N` is the number of items in `X`.  In this case, `f(k) = k.html()`, `k = reply`, and `X = self.replies.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [django-threadedcomments](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments).

Also, the parent-reply relationship isn't really a `ManyToMany`—it's a a parent-child `OneToMany`, because a comment (in traditional threaded comment models, anyway) can only be a reply to, at most, one other comment.

Comment: That link is way over my head. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is fixing your model. Look up rather than looking down.

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_children(self):
        return Discussion.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

When something doesn't have a parent, it's a root thread. When it does, it's a reply.

Your display logic needs to change a bit. Instead of iterating all comments, iterate the top-level posts. Your `comment.html` file might look like this:

```
{{ comment.message }}
{% for comment in comment.get_children %}
    {% include comment.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

In your main template you'd have:

```
{% for comment in base_comments %}
    {% include 'comment.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

And in your view, add `'base_comments':Discussion.objects.filter(parent=None)` to your context.

There's of course a UI element to this where you need to format things and handle the replying process, but I'll leave that up to you.

And don't forget that you can outsource all this very easily. I use Disqus very effectively.